# Filter history between lines?

Tags: command-history

I have my system setup to record a very large amount of history so I can search past commands for later use.

I want to filter the `history` command to get a range of lines numbers. For example say I want history between lines 500 and 600. What's the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

`Sed` can be used to filter between lines:

```
history | sed -n 500,600p
```

**Old Answer:**

```
history | grep [5-6][0-9][0-9]
```

*Down-side is false positives for any other commands which include any number between 500-600.*

Comment: P.S. sorry for answering my own question so quickly.